# How to resize a line with the text height with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling, quoting

I made a new style of quoting. But I have to put the  line height and width of the quote manually. Someone have a solution for make a environment with just 2 or 3 parameters?  The quote, the author and the width of the quote environment?

Here is my code:

```
\def\linesize{1.50} % The height of my line
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray!75] (0,0) -- (0,\linesize);
\draw[gray!75] (0,0.5*\linesize) node [right] {Alfred de Musset};
\draw (0,0.5*\linesize) node [left] {%
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\begin{flushright}
Entre presque oui et oui, il y a tout un monde.
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And a second question, how to choose the text position of my quote? (right, left of the center line)  all this in an  environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily TikZ processes the content of nodes as box so you can exchange the `{ .. }` with `\bgroup .. \egroup` and split the picture there, so it is placed in a `\begin{..}` and `\end{..}`. The `linesize` parameter can also be added as argument or simply calculated from the quote size.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\def\linesize{1.50} % The height of my line
\newenvironment{myquote}[2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[gray!75] (0,0) -- (0,\linesize);
        \draw[gray!75] (0,0.5*\linesize) node [right] {#2};
        \draw (0,0.5*\linesize) node [left] \bgroup
            \begin{minipage}{#1}%
            \begin{flushright}%
}%
{%
            \end{flushright}%
            \end{minipage}%
        \egroup;
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{myquote}{.5\textwidth}{A.U.~Thor}
    A quote is a quote is a quote!
\end{myquote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here an advanced version which doesn't require `\linesize` and uses more of the TikZ parameter instead of manual environments:

```
\newenvironment{myquote}[2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [gray!75] node [right] {#2};
        \node (QUOTE) [left,text width={#1},text ragged left] \bgroup
}%
{%
        \egroup;
        \draw [gray!75]
            ([yshift=5pt]QUOTE.north east) -- ([yshift=-5pt]QUOTE.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

To change the quote the the right side instead you would need to change `left` to `right` and vice versa as well es change `east` to `west` in the second implementation. You could define your own options to do this, but this would be a little overkill. I would just define the environment again e.g. as star version, which uses the same definition but with that values exchanged.