# How to make a textbox with this TikZ code ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes, coordinates

I made this with TikZ :

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\def\banlen{3}
\xdefinecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{62,96,111} % Neutral Blue
\def\bancolor{mycolor}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0.25,0.25) rectangle (5,-2); %
\fill[\bancolor](0,0) -- (0.25,-0.25) -- (0.25,0); % Coin bas-gauche
\fill[\bancolor](\banlen,0.5) -- (\banlen-0.25,0.75) -- (\banlen-0.25,0.5); %Coin haut-droit
\fill[\bancolor!75] (0,0) rectangle (\banlen,0.5); % Rectangle (banner)
\draw (\banlen/2,0.25) node {Box name};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

How to add text in, adjust the banlen value with the Boxname text and adjust the box size ? And how to make a environment with a color parameter ?

I have some difficult with the coordinates :s

Thanks.

Comment: General note: Do not use `\def\bancolor{mycolor} .. \fill[\bancolor]` but `\tikzset{bancolor/.style={mycolor}} .. \fill[bancolor]` or even better `\colorlet{bancolor}{mycolor} .. \fill[bancolor]`.

Comment: I added the resulting box as image for you now. If you want to make an environment out of it see my answer [How to resize a line with the text height with TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22206/how-to-resize-a-line-with-the-text-height-with-tikz/22207#22207) which applies also here.

Comment: Thanks for the add. I can't post images, I didn't already registered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend to use nodes and their coordinates to draw the lines and not to do this manually. TikZ allows you to write `\node \bgroup .. \egroup;` instead of `\node { .. };` and therefore you can wrap a node and the whole `tikzpicture` around the content of an environment. If you use font size specific units, i.e. `ex` and `em`, the whole box will scale nicely with the font size:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\xdefinecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{62,96,111} % Neutral Blue
\colorlet{bancolor}{mycolor}

\def\bancolor{mycolor}
\newenvironment{mybox}[3][]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[#1]%
        \def\myboxname{#3}%
        \node [draw,inner sep=1.5ex,text width=#2]% good options: minimum height, minimum width
            (BOXCONTENT) \bgroup\rule{0pt}{3ex}\ignorespaces
}{%
        \egroup;
        \node [right,inner xsep=1em,fill=bancolor!75,outer sep=0pt,text height=2ex,text depth=.5ex] (BOXNAME) 
            at ([shift={(-1em,0pt)}]BOXCONTENT.north west) {\myboxname};
        \fill[bancolor] (BOXNAME.north east) -- +(-1em,1em) -- +(-1em,0) -- cycle;
        \fill[bancolor] (BOXNAME.south west) -- +(1em,-1em) -- +(1em,0) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{10em}{Test}
    This is the content
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}{15em}{Test it really good}
    This is the longer content
    This is the longer content
    This is the longer content
    This is the longer content
    This is the longer content
\end{mybox}

\huge

\begin{mybox}{10em}{Test}
    This is the content
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}{15em}{Test it really good}
    This is the longer content
    This is the longer content
    This is the longer content
    This is the longer content
    This is the longer content
\end{mybox}
\tiny

\begin{mybox}{10em}{Test}
    This is the content
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}{15em}{Test it really good}
    This is the longer content
    This is the longer content
    This is the longer content
    This is the longer content
    This is the longer content
\end{mybox}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't really know how to use \bgroup. I have the French TikZ doc. But I dont find anything for \bgroup. (Thanks for your quick reply)

Comment: @iDavid: `\bgroup` is `{` as macro and `\egroup` is `}` as macro. You can't have a `{` on its own in a macro or environment definition, so you need to use `\bgroup` and then `\egroup` instead. However, you can only do this for macros like `\hbox` or (with Tikz) `\node` which process the content as box. It doesn't work for normal macro arguments, e.g. `\texttt\bgroup..\egroup` instead of `\texttt{..}` doesn't work.

Comment: How I can change the width of the box with something like 0.5\textwidth ? I didn't yet very familiar with TikZ. Do you have any site or documentation, tuts for make some useful things like this box ?

Comment: @iDavid: You can configure the width with the first argument, i.e. `\begin{mybox}{.5\textwidth}{<title>}<content>\end{mybox}`. This is internally done with the `text width` option. For documentation and examples you only know the `pgfmanual` and http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was just for the size of characters.

Answer (score 4):

`tcolorbox` is a good tool for this kind of boxes. It uses `TiKZ` as drawing engine and with its recent versions is easier to compound boxes with detached titles like this one. Some examples follow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{bancolor}{RGB}{62,96,111}

\tcbset{myboxstyle/.style={enhanced,skin=enhanced jigsaw,
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=-3mm,yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
coltitle=black,varwidth boxed title=0.7\linewidth,
colbacktitle=#1!75, colback=white,sharp corners,
top=2ex,
boxed title style={sharp corners, boxrule=0pt},
underlay boxed title={
\fill[#1] (title.south west) -- (title.south-|frame.west)--++(0,-.5*\tcboxedtitleheight)--cycle;
\fill[#1] (title.north east) --++(-.5*\tcboxedtitleheight,0)--++(0,.5*\tcboxedtitleheight)--cycle;}},
    myboxstyle/.default=bancolor}


\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{myboxstyle,
title={\hspace*{.5cm}#2\hspace*{.5cm}},#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}{My Title}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}[width=.5\linewidth]{My Title}
A short text
\end{mybox}

\tcbox[myboxstyle=red,title=My title]{A short box}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @PeterGrill    I'm using version 3.21, which is the most recent (10/10/2014). I'm not sure when these keys where introduced but I think within last two or three releases.

Comment: So sorry. I had switched to using TeXLive2013 last night and forgot to switch back... Works great with TeXLive2014!!