# Tikz nodes with `fit=(top)(bottom)` slightly missized

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, environments, nodes

I like to create textboxes via TikZ. I start with [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22406/how-to-make-a-textbox-with-this-tikz-code) flexible example.
And, Yes :) I do create texboxes. Here it is. [image]

But I still have **two** problems..

### Q1

I use `fit` to create light gray rectangular on the left of the text box ([reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124371/tikz-make-node-height-span-several-others)). But `\node(colm)` and `\node(colm2)` are slightly bigger than `\node(BOXCONTENT)`. Why? Any ideas?
[image]

### Q2

Also, I add a second rectangular in order to shift my text to the right inside the node because of my poor knowledge about how to escape from `mybox` environment. Is there a nicer way? (I am sure there is) I tried to use something like`\setlength{\leftmargini}{2pt}` but I am still confused about the part

> ```
> ...
> (BOXCONTENT) {}\bgroup\rule{0pt}{3ex}
> }{%
> \egroup;
> ...
> ```

NOT WORKING!!!
The following **MWE** is reproduces my results.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}

%Define colors
\definecolor{Ccolm}{gray}{0.6}
\definecolor{Cfill}{gray}{0.8}

\newenvironment{mybox}[2][]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[#1]%
      %Get the text
        \node [inner sep=1pt,text width=#2,fill=Ccolm,]
            (BOXCONTENT) {}\bgroup\rule{0pt}{3ex}
}{%
        \egroup;

       %Why they are slighlty bigger than their fit!!!
       \coordinate [left=1em of BOXCONTENT.north west] (top);
       \coordinate [left=1em of BOXCONTENT.south west] (bottom);
        \node(colm)    [fit=(top)(bottom),inner sep=0pt,minimum width=1em,fill=Cfill] {};


      %Because I could not shift the text to the left, not a beatufiul solution
       \coordinate [left=0em of BOXCONTENT.north west] (top1);
       \coordinate [left=1em of BOXCONTENT.south west] (bottom2);
       \node(colm2)  [fit=(top1)(bottom2),inner sep=-0pt,minimum width=1.1em,fill=Ccolm] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{mybox}{15em}
      This is the longer content
      This is the longer content
      This is the longer content
      This is the longer content
      This is the longer content
  \end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

**This one works.** Code from qtikz

```
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\xdefinecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{62,96,111} % Neutral Blue

\definecolor{Ccolm}{gray}{0.6}
\definecolor{Cfill}{gray}{0.8}
\colorlet{bancolor}{mycolor}


\newenvironment{mybox}[2][]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[#1]%
      %

        \node [inner sep=1pt,text width=#2,fill=Ccolm,]
            (BOXCONTENT) \bgroup\rule{0pt}{3ex}{}
}{%
        \egroup;

       %Why they are slighlty bigger than their fit!!!
       \coordinate [left=1em of BOXCONTENT.north west] (top);
       \coordinate [left=1em of BOXCONTENT.south west] (bottom);
        \node(colm)    [fit=(top)(bottom),inner sep=0pt,minimum width=1em,fill=Cfill] {};


      %Because I could not shift the text to the left, not a beatufiul solution
       \coordinate [left=0em of BOXCONTENT.north west] (top1);
       \coordinate [left=1em of BOXCONTENT.south west] (bottom2);
       \node(colm2)  [fit=(top1)(bottom2),inner sep=-0pt,minimum width=1.1em,fill=Ccolm] {};

    \end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{mybox}{15em}
    This is the longer content
    This is the longer content
    This is the longer content
    This is the longer content
    This is the longer content
\end{mybox}
```

Comment: The posted code generates `! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.`

Comment: your example doesn't run so I can't test but are you not missing a `%` here `(BOXCONTENT) {}\bgroup\rule{0pt}{3ex}%%%%%`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle There should be a `;` before `\bgroup`, but then the code doesn't produce the picture given in the OP anyway.

Comment: Yeah, there is something wrong. It was running inside the qtikz, but it is giving an error when I compile with pdflatex as well. Truly sorry to waste your time. I am gonna find it what is the problem.

Comment: @trblnc_dsg Can you post the code that compiled in `qtikz`?

Comment: @HarishKumar added. By the way I was also using inside LyX via Lulatex without error, without `;` before `\bgroup`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use proper tool for each job ;-) Here it is `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{
  enhanced,
  colframe=gray!80,
  colback=gray!40,
  left=2em,right=1ex,top=1ex,bottom=1ex,%boxsep=1em,
  leftrule=4pt,
  rightrule=0pt,
  toprule=0pt,
  bottomrule=0pt,
  arc=0pt,
  %breakable,      %% you may like these three lines
%  nobeforeafter,
%  enhanced jigsaw,
  #1}

\begin{document}
  \begin{mybox}[width=15em]
    This is the longer content
      This is the longer content
      This is the longer content
      This is the longer content
      This is the longer content
  \end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Regarding your code, I am of the opinion that what you are doing may cost you lot. Better don't do things in that way. However, you can get rid of the size variations between `\node(colm)` and `\node(colm2)` and `\node(BOXCONTENT)` by adding `outer sep=0pt` in

```
\node [inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt,text width=#2,fill=Ccolm,]
            (BOXCONTENT) \bgroup\rule{0pt}{3ex}{}
```

[image]