# Tikz: How to move a footnote in a node out of that group?

Tags: tikz-pgf, footnotes, grouping

Apologies for the slightly strange title, I struggled to come up with something else.

I have defined my own quote environment with brackets around the quote. In order to do that I use tikz and the quote content is put in a node. If I now use a     \footnote in this node it is but directly under the quote. I'd rather have the footnote at the end of the page, so how can I "break out" of the local group the tikz node seems to create?

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{environ,xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\NewEnviron{bquote}{%
\noindent%
\par%
\addmargin{30pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\node[text width=0.97\linewidth](q){\BODY};%
\draw[ultra thick,line width=7pt,overlay,gray!30] (q.north west) -- ($(q.north
west) - (15pt,0)$) -- ($(q.south west) - (15pt,0)$) -- (q.south west);%
\draw[ultra thick, line width=7pt,overlay,gray!30] (q.north east) -- ($(q.north
east) + (15pt,0)$) -- ($(q.south east) + (15pt,0)$) -- (q.south east);% 
\end{tikzpicture}%
\footnote{Outside the group}%just a test
\par%
}%

\begin{document}
 \lipsum[1]
\begin{bquote}
\lipsum[3]\footnote{Inside the node and sadly local}
\end{bquote}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to be the common issue with footnote inside boxes like `minipage` and `tabular`. See the TeX FAQ entry for it: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=footintab

Comment: Note that you also can use a normal environment (not a so called pseudo-environment provided by `environ`; which is a great package) as shown e.g. in [How to make a textbox with this TikZ code ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22406/how-to-make-a-textbox-with-this-tikz-code/22408#22408) and [How to resize a line with the text height with TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22206/how-to-resize-a-line-with-the-text-height-with-tikz/22207#22207) (also a quote). This is just a general node and won't help you with the footnotes. It would allow verbatim etc. content.

Comment: @Martin. Actually only with Environ the bracket size calculation works. I guess that the normal \newenvironment does not expand the argument #1. Well I know you know all about the expand-trickery of environ and could tell my what the difference is but that might be a different question

Comment: Not sure what you mean with argument `#1` here, but it works fine with small changes. See my answer.

Comment: Some other smaller tips: It should be `\par\noindent` not `\noindent\par`. And you can use `([shift={(-15pt,0)}]q.south west)` instead of `($(q.south west) - (15pt,0)$)`. Then you don't even need the `calc` library.

Comment: I accepted your solution. Previously when I tried to use \newenvironment the grey brackets size was not calculated correctly. This however might have been another problem and the change to environ did not fix it also I thought it did. At first I thought that with using \newenvironment at the time the size calculation is done for the brackets the size of the node is yet unknown. You proved me wrong here.

Comment: Mmmm, the choice of environment shouldn't influence the node size. There might have simply be some other issue. Note that there is the special `current bounding box` node which can be used to access the (current) whole size of the `tikzpicture`.

Comment: Good hint to get rid of calc. I was searching through the pgfmanual but this function escaped me and is exactly what I was looking for in the first place

Comment: It hides in plain sight :-) `pgfmanual` (v2.10) Section 13 "Specifying Coordinates", p.123: "The general syntax is `([<options>]<coordinate specification>)`." But it takes a little to figure that `<options>` can be used for `shift`s!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`footnote`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/footnote.html) package and wrap the `tikzpicture` in a `savenotes` environment. This stores all internal footnotes which otherwise are collected by the internal `minipage` TikZ uses for `\node [text width=<length>]`.

Here the code with some other improvements:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{bquote}{%
\par%
\noindent%
\addmargin{30pt}%
\begin{savenotes}%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\node[text width=0.97\linewidth](q)\bgroup
}{%
\egroup;%
\draw[ultra thick,line width=7pt,overlay,gray!30] (q.north west) -- ($(q.north
west) - (15pt,0)$) -- ($(q.south west) - (15pt,0)$) -- (q.south west);%
\draw[ultra thick, line width=7pt,overlay,gray!30] (q.north east) -- ($(q.north
east) + (15pt,0)$) -- ($(q.south east) + (15pt,0)$) -- (q.south east);% 
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{savenotes}%
\footnote{Outside the group}%just a test
\par%
}%

\begin{document}
 \lipsum[1]
\begin{bquote}
\lipsum*[3]\footnote{Inside the node and sadly local} bla bla
\end{bquote}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it from other questions, TikZ creates a minipage for nodes, so that explains why the footnote gets put inside the node.  To get the other behavior you want, you can try using `\footnotemark` at the point you want the footnote to appear, then use `\footnotetext{the text of the note}` *outside* the environment so that it appears at the bottom of the page.

You could also try automating the process:

```
\def\pendingfootnotes{}
\let\ex\expandafter
\newcommand\externfootnote[1]{%
  \ex\global\ex\def\ex\pendingfootnotes\ex{\ex\pendingfootnotes\footnotetext{#1}}%
  \footnotemark%
}
```

and at the very end of your environment add

```
\pendingfootnotes
\global\def\pendingfootnotes{}
```

to insert them at the end.  I use "externfootnote" so that if you still want the "normal" `\footnote` behavior, it's still available.  I think you need the `\global` to ensure the changes propagate outside the TikZ environment, but I may be wrong...

Comment: +1 sound idea. The `footnote` package (basically) does that for you. Note that the code accumulation can be done using `\g@addto@macro` or with the macros like `\gappto` provided by `etoolbox`.

Comment: good hint, thank you. Martin created his solution around my example code so I accepted his answer.

Comment: @Martin, thanks for the pointer to `\g@addto@macro`; I knew such a thing existed and I could never remember what it was called... :)