# Create a footnote in a node in a tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, footnotes

Is it possible to create a footnote in a node of a tikzpicture? Preferably the tikzpicture it should also be possible to put that tikzpicture inside a figure environment.

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22472/tikz-how-to-move-a-footnote-in-a-node-out-of-that-group/22474#22474

Comment: Oh, great. I didn't find that. I'll see if it's possible to use it inside a figure too. Thanks