# savenote with tcolorbox, numbering problem

Tags: footnotes, tcolorbox

I use `tikz`-boxes and `tcolorbox` and I want to have the footnotes outside of the boxes at the bottom of the page with the same numbering with the others. To sum up, **I want the tikz or tcolorbox footnotes *NOT* to be different with the others**.

So I tried Martin Scharrer's solution to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22472/tikz-how-to-move-a-footnote-in-a-node-out-of-that-group), that uses `savenotes` environment. I wrap `savenotes` environment around `tikzpicture` and `tcolorbox`. **The `tikz`-box is OK, but not the `tcolorbox`**. The footnote's text is at the bottom of the page (OK with this), but **it has other numbering**.

The code is below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{footnote}

\usepackage{environ}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{[\Roman{footnote}]}

\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=black, fill=white, very thick,
rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=20pt]
\NewEnviron{tikzbox}{
    \begin{savenotes} % I add this!!!
            \begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){
    \begin{minipage}{0.50\textwidth}
            \BODY
    \end{minipage}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{savenotes}% I add this!!!

}

\NewEnviron{Tbox}{
        \begin{savenotes}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,
        breakable]
        \BODY
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{savenotes}

}


\begin{document}

Some main text Some main text Some main text Some main text Some main text Some main text\footnote{The first footnote.}

Other main text Other main text Other main text Other main text\footnote{The second footnote.}

\begin{tikzbox}
Some tikzboxed text Some tikzboxed text Some tikzboxed text\footnote{This is OK.}
\end{tikzbox}

\begin{Tbox}
Some tcolorboxed text Some tcolorboxed text Some tcolorboxed text Some tcolorboxed text Some tcolorboxed text Some tcolorboxed text\footnote{This is not OK. I want this footnote outside of the box, at the bottom of the page and with number [IV].}
\end{Tbox}

\end{document}
```

and this is how it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tcolorbox`es in the end are `minipage`s. You need to revert to normal footnotes by adding suiting definitions for `\@mpfn` and `\thempfn` (I also shortened the code somewhat):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{footnote}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{[\Roman{footnote}]}

\makeatletter
\newtcolorbox{Tbox}{
  enhanced, breakable,
  before upper=\def\@mpfn{footnote}\def\thempfn{\thefootnote}%
}
\makeatother
\makesavenoteenv{Tbox}

\begin{document}

Some main text Some main text Some main text Some main text Some main text
Some main text\footnote{The first footnote.}

Other main text Other main text Other main text Other main text\footnote{The
  second footnote.}

\begin{Tbox}
  Some tcolorboxed text Some tcolorboxed text Some tcolorboxed text Some
  tcolorboxed text Some tcolorboxed text Some tcolorboxed text\footnote{This
    is not OK. I want this footnote outside of the box, at the bottom of the
    page and with number [III].}
\end{Tbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Problem solved!