# Tikz : How to get the normal format or behavior of "footnote/footcite" outside a node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, footnotes

I used a defined quote environment, and in ordrer to display the \footnote or \footcite (for refrences) outside the node, I read in the following thread :[How to move a footnote in a node out](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22472/tikz-how-to-move-a-footnote-in-a-node-out-of-that-group) that we need to use the footnote package and wrap the tikzpicture in a savenotes environment. Indeed, it worked. However, when I use a long 'format' of the footnotes or "\footcite", the output is strange. For example, the width is not the same as the other footnotes of my text. Apparently, the footnote takes the width of the quote. I will appreciate any kind of help. thank you so much

```
\documentclass[oneside, a4paper, 12pt, french]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, top=3cm, headheight=26pt, headsep=25pt, heightrounded]{geometry}
\frenchbsetup{FrenchFootnotes=false} 
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage[babel,french=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow, booktabs, hhline}
\usepackage{xltabular, siunitx, lscape}
\newcounter{tabenum}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} 
\usepackage[explicit, clearempty]{titlesec}
 \usepackage{etoolbox}%
 \usepackage{appendix}
 \usepackage{adjustbox}

 \usepackage{smartdiagram}
 \usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false,colorlinks=true,breaklinks]{hyperref}
 \AtBeginEnvironment{footcitedquote}{\singlespacing\small}
 \AtBeginEnvironment{fancyquotes}{\small}
 \usepackage{footnote}
 \makesavenoteenv{tabular}
 \makesavenoteenv{table}
 \spacing{1.45}



\makeatletter
\tikzset{%
fancy quotes/.style={
text width=\fq@width pt,
align=justify,
inner sep=1em,
anchor=north west,
minimum width=\linewidth,
},
fancy quotes width/.initial={.8\linewidth},
fancy quotes marks/.style={
scale=8,
text=white,
inner sep=0pt,
},
fancy quotes opening/.style={
fancy quotes marks,
},
fancy quotes closing/.style={
fancy quotes marks, 
},
fancy quotes background/.style={
show background rectangle,
inner frame xsep=0pt,
background rectangle/.style={
fill=gray!25,
rounded corners,
},
}
}

\newenvironment{fancyquotes}[1][]{%
\noindent
\begin{savenotes} 
\tikzpicture[fancy quotes background]
\node[fancy quotes opening,anchor=north west] (fq@ul) at (0,0) {``};
\tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(fq@ul.east)
\pgfmathsetmacro{\fq@width}{\linewidth - 2*\pgf@x}
\node[fancy quotes,#1] (fq@txt) at (fq@ul.north west) \bgroup}
 {\egroup;
 \node[overlay,fancy quotes closing,anchor=east] at (fq@txt.south east) 
 {''};
\endtikzpicture
\end{savenotes}
\makeatother
 }

 \begin{document}
 Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some 
 text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text  
 Some text Some text \footnote{SSome text Some text Some text Some text Some 
 text Some text Some text  Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text}

\begin{fancyquotes}
    Comme le chœur des vieillards dans la tragédie antique, ils assistent muets aux actes décisifs; ils ne se mettent en mouvement que pour louer ou gémir, après l'événement qui donne raison ou tort aux protagonistes. La fiction d'une absente présence est commode au théâtre où tout est fiction.\footnote{Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text}

\end{fancyquotes}

\end{document}
```

edited : here is the ouput I get.[image]

Comment: If you have `\begin{fancyquotes}`, shouldn't there be also an `\end{fancyquotes}` in your document?

Comment: Thank you for your remark. Indeed :)

Comment: I edited the code. Thank u

Comment: Unfortunately I get still errors (beyond the one that can be resolved by loading `xcolor` before `tikz`).

Comment: I don't get any erros .May be because I didn't put all my code. It's too long I tried to give just the minimum

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Can you try ? I just edited the code thank you

Comment: Why do you not just try to compile the very snippet that you want to upload here and make sure that it runs through? Please remove all unnecessary packages. And no, your latest version still gives a `Missing \begin{document}` error, and possibly further errors.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I tried to follow your advice and remarks. Code edited and tested Can you try know if it is ok?Thank you

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat bu when I compile this minimal code It seems I don't have the problem I had describe above. I think I need to provide the code I use in ordrer for you or other to help me know where did I get the issu

Comment: You can try replacing `\begin{savenotes}` by `\begingroup\begin{savenotes}` and  `\end{savenotes}` by `\end{savenotes}\endgroup`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I edited the code with the one I'm using I tried to get ride of some packages that I'm sure don't have an impact

Comment: I am not sure if the environment is meant to support footnotes inside the text you feed it with. After all, the text goes in a node. If I was you I'd try to recreate the environment with `tcolorbox` (if it does not yet exist), I believe to remember that this package has more support for footnotes in the boxed text.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I tried to replace \begin{savenotes} by \begingroup\begin{savenotes} and \end{savenotes} by \end{savenotes}\endgroup but nothing change thank you

Comment: Is there any reason you can't do this the old-fashioned way i.e. make the marker and then make the note separately?

Comment: @cfr Thank you for your feedback. Why not? Can you show me how please I'm so new to latex  I will really apprecite you help

Comment: @Siham You can use `\footnotemark` to make the marker and then `\footnotetext` somewhere outside the node to actually create the footnote. This is the standard way of dealing with footnotes in places which don't let you have footnotes.